# Rails simple DRY JSON response questions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, dry

I'm building a Rails API and finding myself falling into the same patter:

```
def some_generic_customer_method

 @customer = Customer.where(id: params[:id]).first
 if @customer.present?
   ##execute some code
 else
   respond_to do |format|
     msg = {:status => "FAILED", :messages => "Could not find customer"}
     format.json  { render :json => msg }
   end
 end
end
```

Is there a way to code clean my API so I'm don't have this check/failed response every API call? Right now this is being called in every one of my methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use before_filter and move fail-check to a private method.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without `before_filter`? This works great for the above example, but sometimes I nest two or more parameter checks on different returned objects. I.e. if a customer order exists. It would be helpful to be able to call a private method directly

Comment: You can have multiple before filters, you can call them only on specific actions (only: [:index, :show]). I don't think there is a more rails-way approach.